# Last row in BigQuery array

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to mark the last row of an array in BigQuery. I can select the last row, but I don't know how to create a new field that says "True" for last row, "False" for all other rows.

This is what I have so far, which gives me the last value of a field, but writes that back to all rows in the array, which is not what I want.

```
SELECT
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    AS STRUCT page_views[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(page_views) -1)].page_view_id AS exit
  FROM
    UNNEST(page_views)) page_views
FROM
  `project.dataset.sessions`
```

**Output:**

[image]

I've tried to add a case statement to compare page_view_id with exit, but I couldn't get the case to work with the struct and array.

**Expected output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is for BigQuery Standard SQL:

```
SELECT * REPLACE(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT e.*, OFFSET = ARRAY_LENGTH(page_view) - 1 AS exit
    FROM UNNEST(page_view) e WITH OFFSET
  ) AS page_view
)
FROM `project.dataset.sessions`
```

The above query leaves all fields as is in place and adds just the `exit` field into the `page_view` array.

For the sample data in your question, the result will be:

```
Row id  page_view.page_view_id  page_view.exit   
1   1   1                       false    
        2                       true     
2   2   3                       false    
        4                       false    
        5                       true     
3    3  6                       true
```